# Can't hook animatescroll plugin to a binding method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still pretty new to js/jQuery but I thought it was best practice to separate code from HTML markup?

I am using http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/ animateScroll, and I am surprised to see
the code attached to the button like so...

```
<div id="MainContent">

<ul id="Gallery" class="container gallery">

    <li><a href="images/full/001.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/002.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/004.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/004.jpg" alt="Image 004" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/005.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/005.jpg" alt="Image 005" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/006.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/006.jpg" alt="Image 006" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/007.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/007.jpg" alt="Image 007" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/008.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/008.jpg" alt="Image 008" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/009.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/009.jpg" alt="Image 009" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/016.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/016.jpg" alt="Image 016" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/017.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/017.jpg" alt="Image 017" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/018.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/018.jpg" alt="Image 018" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/001.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/002.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/004.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/004.jpg" alt="Image 004" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/005.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/005.jpg" alt="Image 005" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/006.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/006.jpg" alt="Image 006" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/007.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/007.jpg" alt="Image 007" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/008.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/008.jpg" alt="Image 008" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/009.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/009.jpg" alt="Image 009" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" class="destroy"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" class="destroy"/></a></li>
</ul>
<button class="top">click me</button>
```

What's even more curious, I tried to use this (which is the nature of my question) and it doesn't work!

jquery:

```
<script src="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.top').bind('click', function (){
    $('#Gallery').animatescroll();
});
});

</script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/animatescroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Make sure you are loading your script after jquery.js.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Have you included the js file which contains the animatescroll function?

Comment: No errors, and I have the .js file included...

Comment: Are you really trying to use jQuery before you include it? Is that literally the ordering of your `<script>` tags as written in your code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the Yury Tarabanko's directions (in comments)
2. Try this code... in case your '.top' element is dynamically generated.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('body').on('click', '.top', function () {
           $('#Gallery').animatescroll();
       });
   });
   ```
3. Always put dependency files before any scripts :

   ```
   <script src="../lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../lib/animatescroll.js"></script>

   <script src="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.top').on('click', function (){
               $('#Gallery').animatescroll();
           });
       });

   </script>
   ```
4. The rest of the code (animatePlugin:) has nothing to do here.

Comment: See my edit and tell me if your animatePlugin code is really put just after the </script> end tag

Comment: I followed your recommendation and tried the code under #4. But still nothing...Thanks though! Could it be the developer created so it would only work via inline placement?

Comment: No it's not. Each inline code can work within <script> tags as well.